# Convert Optaplanner ProjectJobScheduling Dates to LocalDateDime

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to convert the Optaplanner ProjectJobScheduling Dates to LocalDateDime, but I'm facing problems in score calculations. The scores are calculated based on the resources business calendar minutes duration between two dates.

In the ProjectJobSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator.java I have the soft1Score initial set based in only one date. What should I do, is it feasable?
Can someone provide me any samples with real dates?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Look at the optaplanner-examples NurseRostering and ConferenceScheduling (new in 7.6).
Basically, do a find in path for "java.time".